# Drop shadow on hover Div over others Divs

Tags: html, css

I have few divs like that:

```
<div class="tab">
   <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab">
   <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab">
   <h2>Text</h2>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.tab {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border-color: #B6B6B6;
    border-top: solid 1px #B6B6B6;
    transition: 0.3s;
    line-height: 12px;
}
.tab:hover {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    transition: 0.3;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    z-index:1000
}
```

as you can see I want to make div drop shadow when hover over it. But everytime when I hover over div, dropshadow is under another div. Can you help me fix it?

[image]

This is how it's look like when over over last div:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I see the problem.  From your image, it looks like the `box-shadow` is being applied to the hovered `div`.

Comment: take a look http://jsfiddle.net/wp3ryLh8/.  Just need to give a little space in between the divs.

Comment: @dowomenfart it's not solution for me, because I want shadow to be just over div under it.

Comment: I would use an unordered list block (ul > li) and apply the hover to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z-index` property works only on **relative**, **absolute** or **fixed** positioned elements.

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.tab {
  position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sebnukem/wp3ryLh8/4/